# creating a video container that covers the whole screen

Tags: html, css, html5-video

i want to create a video container that covers the whole screen

and the video inside the container covers the whole container and doesn't overflow means container adapts the whole screen size.

and is responsive accordingly.

currently the video is taking its full height..i don't want that

i want its height to be limited to the screen size and there is no scroll.

my html code is

```
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <video autoplay controls>
      <source src="../../assets/movies/joker.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css code is :

```
.video-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.video-wrapper {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.video-container video {
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

please help me with this problem..thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to search _vh_ and _vw_ for css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <video autoplay controls>
        <source src="../../assets/movies/joker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A meta tag like this helps:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You need to change your width and height, CSS features the possibility for view height and view width, so it fits the screen. As already mentioned above:

```
.video-wrapper{
height: 100vh;
width: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: you mean width:100vw?

Comment: yeah, i am not slept out ^^